# /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, makefile, cygwin

I'm trying to run hand gesture recognition openCV sample project from this link https://github.com/simena86/handDetectionCV. I run the make command in cygwin terminal, but i'm getting error. I run following command in cygwin terminal E:\handDetectionCVmaster\make

Output:

```
 Arun@Arun-PC /cygdrive/e/handDetectionCVmaster
    $ make
    g++ -o opencv main.cpp myImage.cpp handGesture.cpp roi.cpp  `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
    /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
    main.cpp:1:39: error: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp: No such file or directory
    main.cpp:2:29: error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
    main.cpp:3:39: error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
    In file included from main.cpp:8:
    myImage.hpp:8: error: 'cv' is not a namespace-name
    myImage.hpp:8: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
    myImage.hpp:15: error: 'Mat' does not name a type
    myImage.hpp:16: error: 'Mat' does not name a type
    myImage.hpp:17: error: 'Mat' does not name a type
    myImage.hpp:18: error: 'Mat' was not declared in this scope
    myImage.hpp:18: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    myImage.hpp:18: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    myImage.hpp:19: error: 'VideoCapture' does not name a type
    In file included from main.cpp:9:
    roi.hpp:9: error: 'cv' is not a namespace-name
    roi.hpp:9: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
    roi.hpp:14: error: expected ')' before 'upper_corner'
    roi.hpp:15: error: 'Point' does not name a type
    roi.hpp:16: error: 'Mat' does not name a type
    roi.hpp:17: error: 'Scalar' does not name a type
    roi.hpp:19: error: 'Mat' has not been declared
    In file included from main.cpp:10:
    handGesture.hpp:11: error: 'cv' is not a namespace-name
    handGesture.hpp:11: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
    handGesture.hpp:18: error: 'Point' was not declared in this scope
    handGesture.hpp:18: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:18: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:18: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:18: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:20: error: 'Point' was not declared in this scope
    handGesture.hpp:20: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:20: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:20: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:20: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:21: error: 'Vec4i' was not declared in this scope
    handGesture.hpp:21: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:21: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:21: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:21: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:22: error: 'Point' was not declared in this scope
    handGesture.hpp:22: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:22: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:23: error: 'Rect' does not name a type
    handGesture.hpp:24: error: 'Mat' has not been declared
    handGesture.hpp:29: error: 'Rect' does not name a type
    handGesture.hpp:44: error: 'Point' has not been declared
    handGesture.hpp:44: error: 'Point' has not been declared
    handGesture.hpp:44: error: 'Point' has not been declared
    handGesture.hpp:53: error: 'Scalar' does not name a type
    handGesture.hpp:55: error: 'Point' has not been declared
    handGesture.hpp:55: error: 'Point' has not been declared
    handGesture.hpp:56: error: 'Vec4i' was not declared in this scope
    handGesture.hpp:56: error: template argument 1 is invalid
    handGesture.hpp:56: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    main.cpp:15: error: 'cv' is not a namespace-name
    main.cpp:15: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token
    main.cpp:19: error: 'FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: which one should i install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you miss the pkg-config installation. That is what is also causing the rest of the errors as the output of the `pkg-config` command could not be invoked, respectively.

Go to the following url, grab it and install it:

```
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/pkg-config_0.26-1_win32.zip
```

Please note that you might need to install further dependencies from that site, but then it oughta work, basically.

Comment: When i try to install from this path E:\AR\openCV\pkg-config_0.26-1_win32\bin. i got below error: The program can't start because libglib-2.0-0.dll is missing from your computer

Comment: @user3496826: see `Please note that you might need to install further dependencies from that site, but then it oughta work, basically.` in my post. IOW, get http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/glib/2.28/glib_2.28.8-1_win32.zip and http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/dependencies/gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32.zip

Comment: Is i need to install all the dependencies from that link?

Comment: @user3496826, yes, but see the two links in my comment for your convenience.

Comment: How can i install intl.dll from gettext-runtime_0.18.1.1-2_win32\bin

Comment: @user3496826: just put the intl.dll beside the pkg-config binary, so into the directory where the pkg-config binary was placed or you are planning to place it. This bin directory should be somewhere within your cygwin installation, I imagine.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand

Comment: I put intl.dll to inside glib_2.28.8-1_win32\bin folder and also put inside pkg-config_0.26-1_win32\bin inside folder. When i run the glib then im getting unexpected windows stop

Comment: No, you have to put all this into the cygwin bin folder, wherrever the rest of the binaries are on your system.

Comment: This is my path of file :                             E:\AR\openCV\pkg-config_0.26-1_win32\bin\pkg-config
E:\AR\openCV\glib_2.28.8-1_win32\bin\gspawn-win32-helper

Comment: You mean i need to put these 3 into cygwin folder: gspawn-win32-helper
intl.dll
pkg-config

Comment: yes, into the bin folder, where rest of the binaries are (preferably not system).

Comment: I'm getting below error while putting inside cygwin bin: g++ -o opencv main.cpp myImage.cpp handGesture.cpp roi.cpp  `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
/usr/bin/pkg-config.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0-0.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: You need to put glib in there from the glib package you downloaded.

Comment: I didn't get from you.

Comment: This file glib_2.28.8-1_win32.mft?